# Can a entrepreneur hire a self-employed business owner?

Tags: self-employment, employment, business, europe, job-offer

Let's say that a guy founded a new business he owns, and became CEO of his small company. Can a rich Entrepreneur offer that guy a job?

Comment: Sure.  Why do you think it would not be possible?  What's the purpose of the question?

Comment: I thought bosses don't hire bosses, and I simply don't know how that works. I was also under the impression that the entrapanear dominates the hired boss's company.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. From a hiring standpoint, "bosses" are employees just like everyone else. I do not know any legal reason why they couldn't be hired by another firm.

Comment: If you own your own company and a guy from another company asks to hire you, then your company works for another company, right? It's like you barely own your own company.

Comment: There may be differences in some countries, but in the US and everywhere else I know of, this is not how it works.  The company is its own entity, and employees are not "owned" - employees can own companies that are completely independent from their "employer".

Comment: You just described what every self-employed contractor does every day.

Comment: I'm sorry you guys. I never been to business school, so I don't know basic things like this

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I can by all means start my own company and name myself CEO. If Bill Gates wanted to hire me, I'll take the offer and still be CEO of my own company. Now, whether or not my company makes money and survives is another question.

This is the basis of self-employed individuals who contract out their services.